# Table row expansion with same column schema

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

I have a el-table with no row expansion supported currently. Depending on if the row has a particular object in it, I wish to provide a feature to support its row expansion.

The parent row object and child row object have exact data structure as shown in the figure but a different child id and I am trying to fit it in the same table:

I tried to follow this (table 1 here) but for some reason it doesn't work. I added

```
:tree-props="{children: 'children', hasChildren: 'hasChildren'}">:

https://codepen.io/pen/
```

It would be great to understand how this works.

[image]

Comment: Could you share some code of what is not working?

Comment: @dreijntjens. thanks for your comment here. I got it working using by following this code pen: https://codepen.io/metamet/pen/rrBEZr
Also it seems like I had an outdated element ui library 2.4.x and the tree-props are supported in 2.15.x.